# iOS active assertions beyond permitted time error when importing from Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, import, assertions

I was under the impression that the "active assertions beyond permitted time" error was for when an app is first loading. However, today I was testing my app, doing a batch import from Facebook using iOS 7, and the app crashed with this error.

Specifically, I am calling:

[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

twice for each friend chosen from the friend selector (two different urls). The crash happened when I tried to import 10 people.

I am confused - by this point, the app is fully launched. Why is this assertion happening here?

Crash log portion:

```
Incident Identifier: 0A705B17-FE23-4585-B3EF-89E34F4A4E89
CrashReporter Key:   a9ef164d188c1490dffbe7fdd3c467823e2f3c19
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:             MyApp [3366]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/9CEDB552-C091-4FD7-AF1F-BE39A9D07C67/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.mycom.myApp
Version:             1.5.2 (1.5.2)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-11-24 14:56:00.894 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
MyApp[3366] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x145564c0> identifier: Suspending process: MyApp[3366] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:28 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 3.010 (user 3.010, system 0.000), 49% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.005, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a6b9adc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a603fa0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 172
2   CFNetwork                       0x2f9426e0 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 264
3   Foundation                      0x3070a7ae +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 110
4   Foundation                      0x306da8c6 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfURL:] + 182
5   Foundation                      0x306da7f6 +[NSData(NSData) dataWithContentsOfURL:] + 38
6   MyApp                       0x0020e1a8 +[FacebookHelper imageForObject:] (FacebookHelper.m:910)
7   MyApp                       0x0021bfe4 -[PersonViewController(Facebook) importFriend:withCompletion:] (PersonViewController+Facebook.m:110)
8   MyApp                   0x0021bc2a -[PersonViewController(Facebook) importFriends:] (PersonViewController+Facebook.m:70)
9   Foundation                      0x30758386 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 410
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2fd490dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2fd48cf2 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 778
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2fd4708e __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2fcb1c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2fcb1a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x3499027e GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x32555044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  MyApp                       0x000fc146 main (main.m:5)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a615ab4 start + 0
```

and here is the code snippet:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageForObject:(NSString *)objectID {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=%d&height=%d",objectID,IMAGE_MAXWIDTH,IMAGE_MAXHEIGHT];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
    return image;
}
```

EDIT: Would this allow me to use the returned image to save on my main thread to my app delegate managedObjectContext? In other words, is the thread-safe, or do I need to create and manage an entire new managedObjectContext and then merge it, etc.? And will making multiple closely spaced calls to this revised method, as opposed to the above, help me to avoid the "active assertions beyond permitted time" error?

```
+ (UIImage *)imageForObject:(NSString *)objectID {

    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=%d&height=%d",objectID,IMAGE_MAXWIDTH,IMAGE_MAXHEIGHT];
    __block UIImage *image;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        });
    });
    return image;
 }
```

Comment: How much time has passed since you called that method?

Comment: What do you mean? Since when?

Comment: Do you mean how much time between calls?

Comment: The time that passes since the method call and the crash, can you also maybe provide the fill source of your method? I don't think that the line you provided really is the source of the problem

Comment: See crash log above..

Comment: are you running this on your UI Thread? try using a background thread from GCD  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{  YOUR CODE HERE });

Comment: 0x000000008badf00d indicates that the Watch Dog killed your app for not responding.  Run any time consuming imports on a background queue using `GCD` or `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Is there any way to grab the images on the background thread but them save them to the app delegate managedObjectContext? I am really inexperienced with background threads and every time I try use them things go haywire.

Comment: you only have to do the 'fetching' in the background! You can then go back to the main thread with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // do work here
}); // if this is too complicated to read in the comment format, I could also write an answer to your question, but I'm not sure yet, whether this will fix your issue!

Comment: I think it will fix the issue - it seems to me that the error is because this is happening on the main thread, right?

Comment: Yes, when you totally block the main thread the app is assumed to be stuck. ( and also bad user experience ;) )

Comment: You can write an answer to the question - I would love to see it actually. I will post my code above, and maybe you could show how it would look in GCD?

Comment: But also - wouldn't this be an object created in a different context? Won't I have to do something with contexts then?